# How to avoid putting the HttpSession in every method of a Spring controller?

Tags: spring-mvc

When in a method of a controller I need to retrieve some data from the session (often an ID that I use for user permissions and per user customization of the webpage), I write methods like this:

```
@RequestMapping("something")
public ModelAndView doSomething(HttpSession session) throws AuthorizationException{

PerUserModelBean bean = getSessionRelatedInfo(session);

bean.checkPermissions();



...do my stuff...

}
```

Which is boring because I have to repeat the session parameter for each method and I have to put that code at the beginning of each method. Not only boring, if I want to change that I have to go across all methods and change it. I'd like that session info retriavial and the checkPermissions method get called automatically before my method, and then *somehow* have the bean variable (perhaps as a threadlocal?) automatically filled according to the session contents. Is there some way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the below method to a super class which you can use as a Base for common functionality. I am sure you have one already in place so all child classes will inherit it.

For executing it before every method execution: you may use Filters/Interceptors/AOP, someone else may be able to give you more accurate ideas about that.

```
protected HttpSession getSession(){
        ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
        return attr.getRequest().getSession();
    }
```

Comment: You are right a base controller is in place. I didn't know about RequestContextHolder.... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should place this type of "repeating" code in a `Servlet Filter` or `Spring MVC Interceptor`. That way, you will be able to force a user login if that is relevant to your application.